# Why should we use 'Did you come?' instead of 'Did you came?'?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

I know 'Did' is the past tense of 'Do' and if we want to 
ask question in present tense 'Do you come?' and in past tense it is 'Did you come?'.
Why don't we use 'Did you came?' as came is the past tense of come?

Comment: Because the verb 'did' *takes care* of the past. Did + came would be double past and ungrammatical!

Comment: @ChiragThakar You might want to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer, btw. You might get a much better one! But people are less likely to write another answer for you if you've already accepted one! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Yes you are correct. But OP will accept an answer if he think the answer is sufficient for his question ;-) But your point is acceptable +1 for your comment ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *DO* takes a bare infinitive. In English verb constructions only one verb can have tense. This is always the first verb. So if *did* is past tense, *come* cannot be. It cannot be present tense either. It must be in the plain form:

- *Did she came. (ungrammatical)
- *Did she comes. (ungrammatical)
- Did she come. (beautiful)

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'Did you come', because 'Did you came' is simply ungrammatical. Past tense requires only the main part of the verb to be in past tense, any other parts of the verb of the sentence remain in inflexive form.

Answer (score -4):

Because it is a rule of English grammar to write like this whenever a question is asked in past tense.

Comment: An answer that says "because that's how it is" is somewhat lacking. Can you give more reasoning or explanation for this?