# Did + ... + teach/taught?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

When using "did" in a sentence, does that put the verb in present or past tense?
Example:

> What did they *teach* you?

or:

> What did they *taught* you?

Example 2:

> What did he *say*?

or:

> What did he *said*?

Comment: We usually use a bare infinitive after "did".

Comment: Related question, [Where did they go / do they went?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/where-did-they-go-do-they-went) and [Why should we use 'Did you come?' instead of 'Did you came?'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/why-should-we-use-did-you-come-instead-of-did-you-came).

Comment: Aw... *usually?* @V.V.

Comment: Do you form questions in Past Simple otherwise? The comment corresponds the question

Answer (score 0):

1. What **did** they ***teach*** you?
2. What **did** he ***say***?

are the correct forms. Here the verb *do* is used as an [auxiliary verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) and it must be followed by a verb at the [base form](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form). So it's only *do* that undergoes the inflections according to the sentence form (interrogative, negative, affirmative) and it must be changed accordingly while the main verb is unaltered. Also have a look at [do-support](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support).